# VB.NET, C#:I need a stored procedure to return three rows, how should i store them?

Tags: c#, vb.net

Usually i just use a dictionay for key value pairs but I am expectig three columns.

then I need to compare the search term to see if it matches any value in the second column.

Comment: Why not load the three values into a statically typed object with three properties?  (And, since you were unclear about rows/columns, if there are multiple rows just load them into an `IEnumerable<>` of this object.)

Comment: because i need to cache the result, which was working fine wehn all i needed was two values, so i used a dictionary, now i need three vals

Comment: There's no reason why you wouldn't be able to cache any data at any layer of the application.  How does your caching work now?  If you need to cache the object, just cache the object.  Unless the caching system is broken, it should be no different whether the object is a Dictionary or any other object.  I imagine all it needs to be is serializable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class YourDatum 
{
  int Id { get; set; }
  string Value1  { get; set; }
  string Value2 { get; set; }

  public bool Match(string term)
  {
      return Value2.ToUpperInvariant() == term.ToUpperInvariant();
  }
}

var cachedResults = new Dictionary<int, YourDatum>();

//your database calls go here
foreach (var dbRow in dbRows) 
{
   cachedResults.Add(
      idFromDb, 
      new YourDatum {Id=idFromDb, Value1=valueFromDb1, Value2=valueFromDb2});
}

//find a match in the results later on...
string searchTerm = "abcdef";
List<YourDatum> matches= 
    (from datum in cachedResults where 
    datum.Match(searchTerm) select datum).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

You could just return a DataTable if you wanted to do it quick and dirty. Otherwise, if the data represents something, you could create your own class to hold the three values in three properties on the object.

```
public class MyDataObject
{
  public string Value1 { get; set; }
  public string Value2 { get; set; }
  public string Value3 { get; set; }

  public bool MatchesSearchTerm(string term)
  {
    return Value2.Equals(term, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
  }
}
```

Comment: I don't advise my naming convention, surely you'll have something more meaningful in regards to the data you are working with.

Comment: i need to cache the result of the query, is that cachable

Comment: Any object can be "cacheable" depending on what kind of cache you're using. A cache is as simple as a dictionary, like you said. See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

What is "the search term"?  Why do you need to store rows in the first place?

Assuming you have a good reason to store results locally and you only care about "any value in the second column", you may want to explore storing a `List<dataTypeOfSecondColumn>`.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class QueryCache
{
    public class DataObject
    { 
       public bool Data1 { get; set; }
       public string Data2 { get; set; }
       public int Data3 { get; set; }
    }

    Dictionary<string, DataObject> _cache = new Dictionary<string, DataObject>();    

    public void AddToCache(DataObject obj_)
    {
        _cache.Add(obj_.Data2, obj_);
    }

    public bool ExistsInCache(string searchTerm_)
    {
        return _cache.ContainsKey(searchTerm_);
    }

    public DataObject this[string searchTerm_]
    {
        get
        {
             return _cache[searchTerm_];
        }
    }
}
```